# How can I write messages in a specified channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In 0.16 I just said "client.get_channel("ID"), and could work with it. Now everything changed and when I try this, it says me "client" has no attribute "get_channel"...

So I tried "guild", because the API told me so on their Website.
Iam going to put this in another command, but this shows my problem...

```py
     @commands.command()
     async def test(self, ctx):
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id="573422681983025193")
        await channel.send(content="Test")
```

I tried "id", in stead of "channel_id", no kind of "id", just client.get_channel, but nothing worked!

Comment: Have you tried using an int instead of a string for the id?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Remove the quotes. Just `get_channel(573422681983025193)`

Comment: OH, I tried this, and it worked :) I dont know why, but it worked...

Comment: You should read the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Minn, who told me the answer! 
You have to use guild.get_channel(ID) , without the "" for a String...
I thought I tried it, but it was just with client.get_channel(ID), so use

```py
guild = ctx.message.guild
channel = guild.get_channel(ID)
await channel.send(content="Test")
```